# Handle Transitivity in Python

Tags: python

I have set of pairwise relationship something like this

```
col_combi = [('a','b'), ('b','c'), ('d','e'), ('l','j'), ('c','g'), 
             ('e','m'), ('m','z'), ('z','p'), ('t','k'), ('k', 'n'), 
             ('j','k')]
```

Number of such relationship is big enough to check it individually. These tuple indicates that both values are same. I would like to apply transitivity and find out common groups. Output would be like following:

```
[('a','b','c','g'), ('d','e','m','z','p'), ('t','k','n','l','j')]
```

I tried following code but it has bug,

```
common_cols = []
common_group_count = 0

for (c1, c2) in col_combi:
    found = False
    for i in range(len(common_cols)):
        if (c1 in common_cols[i]):
            common_cols[i].append(c2)
            found = True
            break
        elif (c2 in common_cols[i]):
            common_cols[i].append(c1)
            found = True
            break
    if not found:
        common_cols.append([c1,c2])
```

Output of above code is following

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'g'], ['d', 'e', 'm', 'z', 'p'], ['l', 'j', 'k'], ['t', 'k', 'n']]
```

**I know why this code is not working.** So I would like to know how can I perform this task.

Thanks in advance

Comment: looks like a union-find problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

Comment: You may like this [python-dictionary-of-sets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32264099/merge-python-dictionary-of-sets/32265766#32265766)

Comment: You need to specify whether you want to preserve the tuple ordering in your output "chain".  i.e. does the output need to be as you present `[('a','b','c','g'), ('d','e','m','z','p'), ('t','k','n','l','j')]` (tuple ordering preserved) or is that entirely equivalent to (e.g.) `[('a','c','g','b'), ('d','e','m','z','p'), ('t','l','j','k','n')]` for you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can approach this as a graph problem using the [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io) library:

```
import networkx

col_combi = [('a','b'), ('b','c'), ('d','e'), ('l','j'), ('c','g'), 
             ('e','m'), ('m','z'), ('z','p'), ('t','k'), ('k', 'n'), 
             ('j','k')]

g = networkx.Graph(col_combi)

for subgraph in networkx.connected_component_subgraphs(g):
    print subgraph.nodes()
```

Output:

```
['m', 'z', 'e', 'd', 'p']
['t', 'k', 'j', 'l', 'n']
['a', 'c', 'b', 'g']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can implement a solution using [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) and union/intersection operations.

```
col_combi = [('a','b'), ('b','c'), ('d','e'), ('l','j'), ('c','g'), 
             ('e','m'), ('m','z'), ('z','p'), ('t','k'), ('k', 'n'), 
             ('j','k')]

from itertools import combinations

sets = [set(x) for x in col_combi]

stable = False
while not stable:                        # loop until no further reduction is found
    stable = True
    # iterate over pairs of distinct sets
    for s,t in combinations(sets, 2):
        if s & t:                        # do the sets intersect ?
            s |= t                       # move items from t to s 
            t ^= t                       # empty t
            stable = False

    # remove empty sets
    sets = list(filter(None, sets)) # added list() for python 3

print sets
```

Output:

`[set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'g']), set(['p', 'e', 'd', 'z', 'm']), set(['t', 'k', 'j', 'l', 'n'])]`

Note: [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) for `itertools.combinations`

Comment: Did he really want that?

Comment: Your code is giving me unique values over list of list. Are you sure you understood my problem?

Comment: @vrajs5 I fixed the solution

Comment: @wap26 - I don't know but code is working well with 2.7.2 but giving me <filter object at 0x7fee21d81400> in python 3

Comment: @vrajs5: Change `sets = filter(None, sets)` to `sets = list(filter(None, sets))`

Comment: Hmm - I just tried it and it doesn't give a null list, it gives the output you'd expect...

Comment: Does `sets = [s for s in sets if s]` also give an empty list for you in Python 3?

Comment: @vrajs5: What output do you get in Python 3 if you omit the filter operation?

Comment: @PM 2Ring, used `list()` in solution

Answer (score 1):

A solution with itertools, you can take a look.

```
lst =[]
import itertools
for a, b in itertools.combinations(col_combi, 2):
    for i in a:
        if i in b:
            lst.append(set(a+b))



for indi,i in enumerate(lst):
    for j in lst:
        if i == j:
            continue
        if i & j:
            lst[indi] = i|j
            lst.remove(j)


print lst
```

Output of this is:

```
[set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'g']), set(['k', 'j', 'l', 'n']), set(['e', 'd', 'm', 'p', 'z'])]
```

Of course this can be made more efficient. I will try to update soon.

Answer (score 0):

From the code after elif you assume the relationship is reflexive.
Your algorithm fails if the pairs are not provided in a specific order.

Example:

```
(b, c) (a, b) (c, d)
```

will end up with two sets

```
b, c, d
```

and

```
a, b
```

The problem is about partitioning a set using an equivalence relation. Understanding the set theory background helps identifying a library that can solve the problem. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation .

Comment: Yes. I found why it is not working, before posting it here.

Comment: @vrajs5: You should have mentioned that important information in the question.

Comment: @vrajs5: I did read the bold letters, so I knew that _you_ knew why your algorithm was defective. But you _didn't_ tell _us_ why it was defective. It would've been helpful if you'd said something like what Tarik has mentioned in this answer. Anyway, it's no big deal.

Comment: @PM2Ring He knew that you knew that he knew why his algorithm was defective...lol. Just kidding :-)

Comment: I knew you were going to say that. ;-)